# The type or namespace 'SKYPE4COMLib' could not be found - Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Apologies for the vague title.

I am integrating Skype in to my Unity application. So I added Skype4Com.dll in Visual Studio and the plugins folder of my Unity project, but the editor throws  "error CS0246: The type or namespace name `SKYPE4COMLib' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

When I added the same dll to a different windows form application, the application built successfully.

Here is the code,

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SKYPE4COMLib;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
   void Start()
   {
      Skype skype = new Skype();
      if (!skype.Client.IsRunning)
      {
        skype.Client.Start(true, true);
      }
   }
}
```

The dll has been added as a reference in Visual Studio.

[image]

Below is the error in Unity
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Double click your reference and use the object explorer to explore the namespaces. Maybe SKYPE4ComLib is the dll name, but not the namespace one

Comment: @IronSlug : Thank you for your reply. The dll and namespace names are the same.

Comment: If you added the DLL from visual studio and linked in project references from visual studio try to remove it and add from unity editor (just drag from your origin directory at your OS directory explorer to plugins directory on your unity editor and let unity run their asset's importers correctly).

Comment: @Frohlich: I tried that and it didn't work either. I am not sure why Unity doesn't like this dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. The Skype4COMLib.dll that I got from C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Skype was not the correct dll. Unity was looking for Interop.SKYPE4COMLib.dll

Comment: so where did you find Interop.SKYPE4COMLib.dll ?? can you post your entire code? Were you able to launch skype from Unity app?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your dll is compatible with Unity? Unity 5 only supports up to .Net 3.5 when importing dlls.

Comment: I have checked that and it is compatible with Unity 5